# Calculation in oracle using SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi I am using orcale and I have created a join between tables. I am now trying to insert a calculation but it keeps coming up with the same error message "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended"
The code i have produced is this..

```
select   "CUSTOMER"."CUST_ID" as "CUST_ID",
 "CUSTOMER"."CUST_TITLE" as "CUST_TITLE",
 "CUSTOMER"."CUST_FORENAME" as "CUST_FORENAME",
 "CUSTOMER"."CUST_SURNAME" as "CUST_SURNAME",
 "CUSTOMER"."CUST_ADDRESS_1" as "CUST_ADDRESS_1",
 "CUSTOMER"."CUST_ADDRESS_2" as "CUST_ADDRESS_2",
 "CUSTOMER"."CUST_TOWN-CITY" as "CUST_TOWN-CITY",
 "CUSTOMER"."CUST_COUNTY" as "CUST_COUNTY",
 "CUSTOMER"."CUST_POST_CODE" as "CUST_POST_CODE",
 "CUSTOMER"."CUST_TEL" as "CUST_TEL",
 "CUSTOMER"."CUST_EMAIL" as "CUST_EMAIL",
 "MENU_ITEM"."PRODUCT_PRICE" as "PRODUCT_PRICE",
 "ORDER_ITEM"."QUANTITY" as "QUANTITY",
 "ORDER_ITEM"."ORDER_ID" as "ORDER_ID",
 "ORDER_DETAILS"."ORDER_ID" as "ORDER_ID"
from     "ORDER_DETAILS" "ORDER_DETAILS",
 "ORDER_ITEM" "ORDER_ITEM",
 "MENU_ITEM" "MENU_ITEM",
 "CUSTOMER" "CUSTOMER"
where   "ORDER_ITEM"."ORDER_ID"="ORDER_DETAILS"."ORDER_ID"
 and     "ORDER_DETAILS"."CUST_ID"="CUSTOMER"."CUST_ID"
 and     "MENU_ITEM"."MENU_ITEM_ID"="ORDER_ITEM"."MENU_ITEM_ID"`
```

this is the code that produces the error message

```
 select  "CUSTOMER"."CUST_ID" as "CUST_ID",
 "CUSTOMER"."CUST_TITLE" as "CUST_TITLE",
 "CUSTOMER"."CUST_FORENAME" as "CUST_FORENAME",
 "CUSTOMER"."CUST_SURNAME" as "CUST_SURNAME",
 "CUSTOMER"."CUST_ADDRESS_1" as "CUST_ADDRESS_1",
 "CUSTOMER"."CUST_ADDRESS_2" as "CUST_ADDRESS_2",
 "CUSTOMER"."CUST_TOWN-CITY" as "CUST_TOWN-CITY",
 "CUSTOMER"."CUST_COUNTY" as "CUST_COUNTY",
 "CUSTOMER"."CUST_POST_CODE" as "CUST_POST_CODE",
 "CUSTOMER"."CUST_TEL" as "CUST_TEL",
 "CUSTOMER"."CUST_EMAIL" as "CUST_EMAIL",
 "MENU_ITEM"."PRODUCT_PRICE" as "PRODUCT_PRICE",
 "ORDER_ITEM"."QUANTITY" as "QUANTITY",
 "ORDER_ITEM"."ORDER_ID" as "ORDER_ID",
 "ORDER_DETAILS"."ORDER_ID" as "ORDER_ID"
   from  "ORDER_DETAILS" "ORDER_DETAILS",
 "ORDER_ITEM" "ORDER_ITEM",
 "MENU_ITEM" "MENU_ITEM",
 "CUSTOMER" "CUSTOMER"
where   "ORDER_ITEM"."ORDER_ID"="ORDER_DETAILS"."ORDER_ID"
 and     "ORDER_DETAILS"."CUST_ID"="CUSTOMER"."CUST_ID"
 and     "MENU_ITEM"."MENU_ITEM_ID"="ORDER_ITEM"."MENU_ITEM_ID"
SELECT PRODUCT_PRICE,
       QUANTITY, 
       PRODUCT_PRICE * QUANTITY AS "TOTAL SPENT"
FROM   MENU_ITEM,ORDER_ITEM
```

Comment: Please post the actual query that's producing the error-message.

Comment: Which of the two queries you posted produces the error?

Comment: this is the code that produces the error message

Comment: @user2179333 Your post contains **2** queries. Which one produces the error: 1st, 2nd, or both?

Comment: A few things come to mind.  Be sure both columns are indeed numerical.  Also, you have no joining conditions on your lower code ("MENU_ITEM"."MENU_ITEM_ID"="ORDER_ITEM"."MENU_ITEM_ID").

Comment: when i put both codes together then the error message appears, when they are both separate they actually work! @PM77-1

Comment: Now, please post the **EXACT** query that gives you this error!  Your error message is often caused by using SQL clauses out of sequence or other syntax typos.

Comment: Ok I will post it now @pm77-1

Comment: sorry for the delay, i have added the code @pm77-1

Comment: You have **two** non-terminated queries here. If you want to run them separately then put ";" at the end of each.

Comment: Have you tried running the 2nd (short) query on its own?

Comment: now it is saying that the identifier is too long?? also yes i have tried the second query, it does work by itself  @pm77-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the SQL is that your second "SELECT" statement opens a new SQL command. If you want to add a new column called "TOTAL_SPENT" to your query that multiplies PRODUCT_PRICE and QUANTITY, add it into the SELECT list of the main query. Adding a second SELECT statement will not merge the results into the first one.

You want something like this:

```
select  "CUSTOMER"."CUST_ID" as "CUST_ID",
 "CUSTOMER"."CUST_TITLE" as "CUST_TITLE",
 "CUSTOMER"."CUST_FORENAME" as "CUST_FORENAME",
 "CUSTOMER"."CUST_SURNAME" as "CUST_SURNAME",
 "CUSTOMER"."CUST_ADDRESS_1" as "CUST_ADDRESS_1",
 "CUSTOMER"."CUST_ADDRESS_2" as "CUST_ADDRESS_2",
 "CUSTOMER"."CUST_TOWN-CITY" as "CUST_TOWN-CITY",
 "CUSTOMER"."CUST_COUNTY" as "CUST_COUNTY",
 "CUSTOMER"."CUST_POST_CODE" as "CUST_POST_CODE",
 "CUSTOMER"."CUST_TEL" as "CUST_TEL",
 "CUSTOMER"."CUST_EMAIL" as "CUST_EMAIL",
 "MENU_ITEM"."PRODUCT_PRICE" as "PRODUCT_PRICE",
 "ORDER_ITEM"."QUANTITY" as "QUANTITY",
 "ORDER_ITEM"."ORDER_ID" as "ORDER_ID",
 "ORDER_DETAILS"."ORDER_ID" as "ORDER_ID",
 PRODUCT_PRICE * QUANTITY AS "TOTAL SPENT"
   from  "ORDER_DETAILS" "ORDER_DETAILS",
 "ORDER_ITEM" "ORDER_ITEM",
 "MENU_ITEM" "MENU_ITEM",
 "CUSTOMER" "CUSTOMER"
where   "ORDER_ITEM"."ORDER_ID"="ORDER_DETAILS"."ORDER_ID"
 and     "ORDER_DETAILS"."CUST_ID"="CUSTOMER"."CUST_ID"
 and     "MENU_ITEM"."MENU_ITEM_ID"="ORDER_ITEM"."MENU_ITEM_ID"
```

Depending on what columns are in the other tables, you may need to qualify PRODUCT_PRICE and QUANTITY with their table names, like the other column references in the SQL.

Comment: thank you so much! it did work and you've saved me branding today is a wasted day on my assignment! thank you